# Did Game Boy emulation exist for the 486 era (MS-DOS and Windows 3.1)?

Tags: emulation, gaming-history

The title says it all: Did we have working emulators for the 486/MS-DOS era back then? Would a 486 be capable enough to run a Game Boy emulator? If so what were they like?

Comment: Yes it was. It was possible to emulate a SNES in DOS, so a gameboy would have been far easier, and should have been doable on a 486.

Comment: I don't think this is a "shopping recommendation" question as there's no request here for a 'present day' MS-DOS-based emulator. So I've edited this to focus more on the historical context surrounding emulation in the DOS era. Up to the community whether they want to reopen this or not.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.**

[Virtual Gameboy](http://fms.komkon.org/VGB/) was the first gameboy emulator available and was first released on MS-DOS.

Today there are various other emulators available that also run on MS-DOS, such as CBEboy, cingb, NO$GB and various others.